# Objective-C determine what objects retain another object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-leaks, retaincount

I have some problems with memory leaks on iPhone (imagine that), and I have a custom object with a retain count of 10.

Is there any way I can know what code triggered the retain count increased for a specific object instance? I am using GHUnit if that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The leaks tool (one of the "instruments" in XCode) is able to analyse that sort of thing, but I don't think you can do it programatically.

Here is a great tutorial: http://mobileorchard.com/find-iphone-memory-leaks-a-leaks-tool-tutorial/

(Update to summarise comments): If you'd like to set a breakpoint in the retain method (to look at the stack trace) you can override the retain method.

Comment: I am using the leaks tool, that is how I actually found it, I just want to figure out how to track a specific memory address really, and when the -retain selector is passed to that, have a breakpoint, that would be awesome, if that can be done..

Comment: Since it's a custom object, I guess you could just override Retain?

Comment: @Richard: Instruments lets you do just that. It shows the full life cycle of the leaked object. You might want to give the documentation a quick once-over with this in mind. Quite useful. :-)

Comment: @joshua Documentation is overrated :) jk I will look right now

Comment: @Richard: Agreed. You should buy a third-party book. I happen to know of one coming out in a few months ... ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Try using the `Build & Analyze`. It can usually tell you if an object is being retained and not released./

Comment: I use that and nothing shows up, i have a situation where two objects retain each other

Answer (score 2):

The retain counts are nearly useless—if something gets `retain`ed and `autorelease`d in a statement, that's perfectly fine, but its retain count will increase by 1.

If you want to find exactly where a particular object is being `retain`ed, override the class's `retain` implementation to test for your object(s), and set a breakpoint there:

```
@implementation MyClass
-(id) retain
{
    if(self == ObjectThatImTracking)
        NSLog(@"[ObjectThatImTracking retain]\n");  // put a breakpoint here
    return [super retain];
}
```

Then run your program in the debugger and look at the call stack when the breakpoint gets hit.

Comment: I will not know what `ObjectThatImTracking` is until run-time, because I will not know the address of the object until runtime

Comment: That is the point;  `ObjectThatImTracking` is a global variable. As soon as you know the object you want to track, then set the variable and the retain will log whenever that object is retained.

Answer (score 0):

Did you trying to find all retain cases of your class in modules? Maby it helps..